# derivative of a matrix respect to another matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives

> Given the weight graph $G(V,E,w)$, we define the adjacency matrix $A$ by
>   $$A_{ij}=\begin{cases} w_{ij},&\text{if }(i,j) \in E, \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}.\end{cases}$$
>   The degree matrix of a weighted graph is a diagonal matrix $D$ such that
>   $$D_{ii}=\sum_j A_{ij}.$$
>   Which is the derivative of $P=D^{-1/2}AD^{-1/2}$ with respect to $A$?
>   $$\frac{\partial P}{{\partial\ A}}=\frac{\partial\big(D^{-1/2}AD^{-1/2}\big)}{\partial\ A}$$

I was wondering if any one could help me to find out the answer.

Comment: You can add equations using [LaTeX](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX).

Comment: Go to Google and type in "Matrix Cookbook."

Comment: I typed it according to  "Matrix Cookbook".